# How to get a formatted string from the selected value of a DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, string, format, datetimepicker

Compiler does not recognize the `GetText` method in `DateTimePicker` Element.

By Changing the Arguments,it does not compile again!

```
DateOfBirth = 
dateTimeSelectorDateOfBirth.GetText("yyyy/mm/dd");
```

Although My Error is Missing a cast, by searching I can not solve my Compilation Problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have and the complete error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no GetText in the WinForms DateTimePicker control.

There is a Text property and ToString method as well as Value.

Value is of DateTime type and you can format it to have a string like you want.

So you can achieve your goal by writing:

```
string DateOfBirth = dateTimeSelectorDateOfBirth.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

You can found format information in the specifications:

[DateTime.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_)